# How to check condition and choose return

Tags: python-3.x

In C# I would do this if I wanted the word 'Many' to display if the count was 10 or more:

```
int count = 10;
var result = count < 10 ? count : "Many";
```

How do you do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `print` function and `if-else` statement:

```
>>> count =10
>>> print('many') if count>=10 else ''
many
```